# How to read column and find corresponding data and print the values?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to write a formula that does the following. It reads the field values from column K. For example the field value is 3. So it goes to Column B and goes to the 3th row and prints the corresponding value from volumn A which is 14152. I have done the following formula but it's giving me a field error.

```
=FIELDVALUE(K3,Sheet5!A1)

Column K:  Column B: Column A:
3          5412      12421
52         4242      24145
32         214141    14152
```

Comment: Just to check, do you have Office 365?

Comment: Yes I do have office 365

Comment: does `=INDEX(A:A,K3)` give you the answer you are looking for?

Comment: No it doesn't but I think it might be close.

Comment: With index is not going to 3rd row of column B and finding the corresding value on Column A which is 14152.

Comment: How does the 3rd row in column B *not* correspond to the 3rd row in column A? They're both the 3rd row. I don't see the point of column B here.

Comment: Actually it does solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much man. This really helped out a lot.